# Fluent NHibernate no data being returned

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have been successfully using NHibernate, but now I am trying to move to Fluent NHibernate.  I have created all of my mapping files and set up my session manager to use a Fluent Configuration.  I then run my application and it runs successfully, but no data is returned.
There are no errors or any indication that there is a problem, but nothing runs.

when using NHibernate, if I don't set my hbm xml files as an embedded resource, this same thing happens.  This makes me wonder what I have to set my Map classes to.  Right now, they are just set to Compile, and they are compiled into the dll, which I can see by disassembling it.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to what may be happening here?

Thanks

```
private ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(
                    IfxOdbcConfiguration
                        .Informix1000
                        .ConnectionString("Provider=Ifxoledbc.2;Password=mypass;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Data Source=mysource")
                        .Dialect<InformixDialect1000>()
                        .ProxyFactoryFactory<ProxyFactoryFactory>()
                        .Driver<OleDbDriver>()
                        .ShowSql()
                    )
                    .Mappings(
                        x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                        //.ExportTo("C:\\mappings")
                    )

                .BuildSessionFactory();
        }
```

Comment: Are proper SQL statements being executed against the database?  What does the logging tell you?

Comment: I am not seeing any sql being executed.  I have showsql set in my config, but there are no statements showing in my console.

Comment: Please post the code for your session manager's configuration.

Comment: When you say "no data is being returned", what are you actually executing that you expect data to be returned from?

Comment: I am executing a criteria query against my database.  it is simple return 25 records from 1 table.  It works fine if I switch back to using my hbm files.

Comment: I think I found part of the problem - I didn't have the scope of the mapping classes set to public.  I added that in and now I am at least getting an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Does the executing assembly contain the fluent mapping classes? I would try:

```
.Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MappedType>())
```

Where `MappedType` is a class that has a fluent mapping.

Answer (score 0):

They should just be set to compile, that's fine. Nothing special needed here. The problem is most likely in your fluent configuration rather than the mapping.

Comment: How can I figure out where the problem is if I am not receiving any error messages?